# Is it possible to show the annotations of method parameters in PHPStorm?

Tags: phpstorm

I would really love to have this feature.. for example:

Here is the annotation for Symfony's `add` method for the request parameter bag

```
     /**
     * Adds parameters.
     *
     * @param array $parameters An array of parameters
     *
     * @api
     */
```

When I type this in the editor: `$request->request->add()` and hit `Cmd+p` inside the `add` method to show the parameters, is there a way for it to show me the annotations as well? or at least show something like `'An array of parameters'` alongside the parameter? I am aware that `option+space` on the method name itself will give me the annotation, but what I really want is for it to show me the annotated docs on a per-parameter basis

Comment: `Ctrl+Q` (View | Quick Documentation) on function/method in advance (you can pin on a side it so it's always visible) -- I think you meant this by `Ctrl+Space`, as this key combo will not show you this sort of annotation.